# linked Model not returning linked data in cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have had this working plenty of times so I am wondering if I have missed something GLARINGLY obvious or subtly hidden.

I have the following code in a model called Wedding:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className' => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'wedding_id'
    )
);
```

and I have the corresponding code in a Model called Photo:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Wedding' => array(
        'className' => 'Wedding',
        'foreignKey' => 'wedding_id'
    )
);
```

but when I view the url /Weddings/ I do not get the linked photographs in the $weddings variable. Here is the db entry in photos:

```
id  name         file     wedding_id
1   Couple Shot  xxx.jpg  1
```

and in weddings:

```
id  name               groom       bride        weddingdate  location_id  photo_id
1   Ike & Tina Turner  Ike Turner  Tina Turner  2010-01-01   1            1
```

What have I missed? Thanks

Comment: Any `$this->Wedding->recursive = -1;` before calling the find() method ? You didn't provide the controller code, so it is difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the recursive when you call the model or before you call the find method:

```
$this->Wedding->recursive = 1;
```

This will pull the associated data.

Comment: aaaaggggghhhhh! For some reason my recursive was set to 0! Thank you, thank you. I knew it would be too obvious rather than hidden.